# Flatten Numpy 3D Array to 2D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 3D numpy array with shape `(10, 20, 3)`, representing an image with 10 rows and 20 columns, where the 3rd dimension contains an array of length 3 of either all zeros, or all ones, for example `[0 0 0]` or `[1 1 1]`.

What numpy method would be most suitable to convert the 3D array to 2D, where the third dimension has been reduced to a single value of either `0` or `1`, depending on whether the array was previously `[0 0 0]` or `[1 1 1]`?

The new shape should be `(10, 20)`, where the value of each cell is either `0` or `1`. So instead of the third dimension being an array, it becomes a integer.

I have had a look at [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), and also [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html), however it looks like both of these methods maintain the same total number of 'cells' (i.e. 10 x 20 x 3 = 600). What I want is to **reduce one dimension down to a single value** so that the total number of cells is now 10 x 20 = 200.

Comment: Why not just use `result = myarray[:, :, 0]`?

Comment: Thanks, this works. I assume this returns the first index of the third dimension, so I'd need to ensure the array is either `[0 0 0]` or `[1 1 1]`, as I imagine `0` would be incorrectly returned if the array is not all zeros, for example `[0, 3, 1]`.

Comment: Exactly. In case you need information from the other elements you could use numpy functions such as `result = np.average(myarray, axis=2)`, `result = np.min(myarray, axis=2)` or `result = np.max(myarray, axis=2)`.